# Simple Way in Java to check if char is in EBCDIC

Tags: java, ebcdic

I'm trying to figure out how to check if a char is in EBCDIC.

One approach would be to have a predefined array with all possible EBCDIC signs, and check if the character can be found in that array.

Is there a better/cleaner way?

Comment: Just to clearify your question, you're not asking how to check if a character is EBCDIC encoded, because Java uses Unicode, you're asking if the Unicode character also existing in the EBCDIC character encoding?

Comment: yes exactly, checking if the Unicode character also exists in the EBCDIC encoding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
boolean canEncode(char ch) {
    Charset charset = Charset.forName("EBCDIC");
    return charset.newEncoder().canEncode(ch);
}
```

The [`CharsetEncoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html) can also check entire Strings.

And there is more conversion support around Charset.

---

Thanks to @BruceMartin and @0x1C1B

Note that there are more than one EBCDIC variants, just like 8 bit ASCII ((US) ASCII being 7 bits). Pick the right code page:
`"Cp037" for US EBCDIC, "Cp1047", ...

You will need the Charset to convert to EBCDIC bytes.

Comment: Are you sure that this is working? Not your code but the encoding you've to load. I've to use a specific EBCDIC code page like `Cp1047` as encoding. `EBCDIC` doesn't work for me.

Comment: You will have to specify a specific EBCDIC encoding e.g. cp037 (US EBCDIC). Characters supported will vary between the various EBCDIC flavors

Comment: As mentioned by @Bruce there are [quite some variations](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=as400toolboxjarmaker-ccsid-encoding-values-supported-by-toolbox-java) available. IBM even open sourced the Toolbox code where mappings to and from Unicode can be found (i.e. [IBM273](https://sourceforge.net/p/jt400/svn/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/com/ibm/as400/access/ConvTable273.java)). As applying the wrong CP to the bytes most likely will result in garbage, probing through all possible charsets and then selecting the one that produces the highest density of "human-readable" characters could be an option

Comment: @RomanVottner One has to compare the special characters on both side: java Unicode and system to detect the correct encoding. One might also list for every character, code point, the `Character.getName(codePoint)`. And then one might use the list of available charsets maybe. Everything not very straightforward.